# Depth-first search maze generation in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a very simple implementation of the Depth-first search random maze generation algorithm. I'm trying to get my head around it, but i just can't understand the neighbor identification part.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Depth-first_search

Maybe someone can provide a simple snippet? :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "the neighbor identification part"? If you're at `(x,y)`, the neighbors are `(x-1,y)`, `(x,y-1)`, `(x+1,y)` and `(x,y+1)`.

Comment: That's obvious. I'm talking about how does that apply to the recursive function itself.

Comment: It is indeed obvious. So obvious in fact that I still don't understand what's unclear to you. You just call the function 4 times with the 4 values I wrote above.

Comment: What is X and Y in your formula?

Comment: Maze's width and height are $total = $width * $height. But, $cell should be what?

Comment: @Jason, I ***think*** you don't understand arrays. Maybe that's what you should be focusing on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to randomly select an edge (Wall) from a vertex. Each vertex has 4 edges (North, South, West, East). First off you want to build a tree with all vertex IMO in Zig-Zag order?

Comment: Not really and it would make it very complicated. Here is a solution in ruby and javascript: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/27/maze-generation-recursive-backtracking. You want to travel the grid and build a spanning tree :).