# Depth-first maze generation in PHP, does anyone have any examples?

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm studying the following algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Depth-first_search

And would love to see a sample implementation in PHP. I have seen the Python and Javascript implementations, but i'm not able to understand how they treat cells.

Comment: Maybe a Ruby implementation would help? http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/27/maze-generation-recursive-backtracking

Comment: Or perhaps this PHP implementation? http://rjheywood.com/projects/3_PHP_Maze_Generator.html. Google is your friend.

Comment: I could use Google, my friend, but I thought that asking humans for good suggestions would be better. What's the purpose of Stack Overflow after all? Don't be an ass, please.

Comment: Thanks for the link Jim, very interesting and well documented.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be an ass, but rather suggesting an alternate and possibly more efficient way to obtain an answer. A quick Google search often returns the answer (frequently to a previous Stack Overflow question like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941624/depth-first-search-maze-generation-in-php) faster than asking here and waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following php class:

http://www.bluepearl-skins.com/forums/topic/7288-php-maze-generator-and-solver-using-gd-module/

And a simplified, procedural version:

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/08/20/step-by-step-perfect-maze-generation-with-php/

I hope this helps!